# WPF: SystemParameters.WindowCaptionButtonHeight returns smaller number than expected

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

We have a window where we have set the WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness to a negative value so that we have glass frame extended over the entire window.

With this, the SystemParameters.WindowCaptionButtonHeight value returns 22 when I am actually expecting something in the range of ~36. I've provided some pictures showing what the current and expected behavior should be.

[Current Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipKpN.png)

[Expected Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk3iA.png)

Currently I am working around this issue by using the WindowCaptionButtonWidth instead of height since it returns the more expected value but this just feels wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the DWM, these system parameters no longer give correct vales. You can still calculate the height by summing up SystemParameters.CaptionHeight, SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness.Left (or whatever other than Top), and SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness.Left (or whatever other than Top).

**However,** things become quite complicated under Per-Monitor DPI environment like Windows 10. These system parameters turn to be useless without correct modifications by System DPI and Per-Monitor DPI. So, if you wish to completely redesign a window, the caption height will be a part of total considerations for Per-Monitor DPI.

Comment: And coming back after the break, I remembered that I had already partially dealt with this issue while getting the system menu to show up when clicking on the app icon. Thanks for the reminder. Now if only Microsoft would make some indication somewhere about how I'm supposed to programmatically get this information accurately with each new OS release.