# SystemInformation.CaptionHeight returns a seemingly incorrect value

Tags: c#, metrics

hope this question finds you well!

This is a quick one. I'm trying to programatically determine the height of the standard window titlebar in Windows.

The project is a WPF (C#) project, with a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` included.

I'm using `SystemInformation.CaptionHeight` (from `System.Windows.Forms`) to get the height of the titlebar area, and am simply printing the value in a temporary TextBox.

The problem: The resulting value doesn't coincide with a screenshot of the window, pasted into Paint and measured. **The value returned from the code is 27**, and as you can see from the image below, even excluding the window border, **the height is actually 32 pixels**. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.captionheight?view=net-5.0), `SystemInformation.CaptionHeight` returns "The height, in pixels, of the standard title bar area of a window."

(This is zoomed in):

[image: Measuring the titlebar in MS Paint shows the height to be 32 pixels]

***TL;DR:** `SystemInformation.CaptionHeight` says the titlebar height is 27, when it's actually 32 (pixels).*

So, am I missing something blatantly obvious, or is it simply that `SystemInformation` isn't providing up-to-date values? Or is there another better way to do this which is always accurate?

(Edit): `System.Windows.SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight` also returns the same result (27).

Comment: It is a dpiAware problem.  At 1920x1080 the monitor runs at 125%, 34/1.25 = 27 when dpi virtualization is turned on.  That's not supposed to happen in a WPF app, there is no cue in the question.  Maybe a 2nd monitor.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "there is no cue in the question", but this is running on a laptop with a 1080p screen, with a secondary 1080p screen attached (no changes to the primary display when the ext. monitor is connected/disconnected). That could very well be the problem though, I don't know what Windows does behind the scenes nowadays with all this device-independent scaling B.S. Is there a way I can programmatically find out this scaling value to do the multiplication, or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Did you find an answer or workaround to this issue?

Comment: I've solved similar issue by adding `SystemParameters.ResizeFrameHorizontalBorderHeight` to `SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight` as proposes in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34553255/536172